# $\int_Bdxdy=\int_{h(B)}dxdy\implies |det [h'(x,y)]|=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ be a bijective function $C^1$ which $\det[h'(x,y)]\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$. Show that if  $$\int_Bdxdy=\int_{h(B)}dxdy$$ for all closed ball $B\subset \mathbb R^2$, then $|\det[h'(x,y)]|=1$.

**My attempt**

By Inverse Function Theorem and bijection of $h$, we have that $h$ is a global diffeomorphism. Then, by Change of Variables Theorem, we have that $$\int_{h(B)}dxdy=\int_{B}|\det[h'(x,y)]|dxdy.$$ So, by hypothesis,$$\int_{B}(1-|\det[h'(x,y)]|)dxdy=0.$$

If $1-|\det[h'(x,y)]|=0$ then the exercise is finished.

But isn't clear for me why $1-|\det[h'(x,y)]|=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = 1 - |\det[h'(x,y)]|.$ Since $h \in C^1$, $f$ is continuous. By the mean value theorem for integrals

$$0 = \int\limits_B f(x)dx dy = f(c) \cdot \mu(B)$$

for some $c \in B$. Since $\mu(B)\neq 0$, it must happen that $f(c)=0$.

Now, take any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and construct a decresing sequence of balls containing $p$, for example $B_n = B(p, {1\over n})$. By the previous result, we obtain a sequence $c_n \in B_n$ such that $f(c_n) = 0$ and $c_n \rightarrow p$ (since $\rho(c_n,p) < {1\over n}$). By continuity of $f$, $f(p) = \lim f(c_n) = 0$.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: @CarlosH.Santos Glad to be of help! Note that the theorem works in a more general setting (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or even on a manifold) with exactly the same proof.